# How to stop routers blocking my applications network traffic

Tags: java, network-programming

I have a application which listens for commands over IP.
The program works fine locally but when I try to send the application commands with a remote address it won't connect.
Is there anyway to get around the router blocking the inbound network traffic?
I'm using JAVA
Thanks.

Comment: Open the port in the firewall, and/or configure port forwarding if there's a NAT gateway inbetween. (If you remotely could easily get through a firewall, there would be no point in a firewall)

Comment: How do applications do this automatically though? I never have to mess around with port forwarding when I want to use other network applications

Comment: They generally don't (Except some apps like skype, who goes to the end of the world and back again to try to do NAT hole punching). You should tell more about what your actual problem and setup is, whether the problem is that you're app is behind firewall or a NAT gateway. Perhaps you're trying to connect 2 applications that's *both* behind a NAT gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a pair of hosts you control, you can open the incoming port.  You might also
succeed using a tunneling program such as Hamachi to effectively set up a VPN linking
the hosts.

If you're talking about a pair of unrelated computers (for example trying to set up
a connection for a game) there's no general solution that doesn't involve installing
and trusting additional software.  The usual solution is to use a public server and
relay the traffic between the end points.